# CSS/HTML - padding issue on Firefox and style override

Tags: html, css, firefox, padding

**My first issue:**

Because of some weird problem with Firefox I have to put these :

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

in every div with background img to avoid problems on Firefox.
I have no problem with these But sometimes I need to use padding-top to make some distance between text and it's above.

If I use both `padding:0` and `padding-top:2px` then the problem is still there. How can I use `padding-top` while having the fix for Firefox?

**Second one:**

I used a global CSS code for all  tags on my page. For example I used the `color:FFF` on all  tags. But sometimes I need to have a specific link to be `color:000`. like this one:

```
<div style="color:000"><a href="#">blabla</a></div>
```

As you know this way I can't make the 'blabla' link in black color, Because I already have style applied for `<a>` tags so it will be in white again. How can I achieve this one?

Comment: can you post your code on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the padding, you can add an extra div inside the previous one, just for padding.

```
<div>
  <div class=PaddingStyle>Content</div>
</div>
```

That way you will keep your fixed div intact.

About your second question, try adding !important to the second style

```
a {color:#000 !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both problems are gone!

Answer (score 0):

In response to #1:

When you say "padding:0", you're saying to set the padding for all directions - left, top, right, and bottom to "0". If your "padding-top:2px" appears before your "padding:0", then your "padding-top:2px" will be ignored.

If you want to modify your styles based on the browser, then I recommend [css browser select](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/). I've used this before and found it quite handy.

Comment: I have already tried using padding-top after padding:0 But no luck! And Thank  you so much for the link I didn't know such technique exist! using that it will be super easy to handle multiple browser issues.

Comment: @xperator: That's odd. Are you using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)? It's great for tracking down styling bugs. You can even edit most values in place and see the effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

To override the color you can add a class to your stylesheet as such:

```
/* Global Link Override */
a:link {
  color:FFF;
}

/* Specific Link Override */
.specialLink a:link {
  color: 000;
}
```

You can then apply it to the link as such, the first will be white and the second black:

```
<a href="#">foo</a>
<div class="specialLink"><a href="#">bar</a></div>
```

Comment: this is the actual code I tried using your instruction But still not working : http://jsfiddle.net/T9SxH/2/

Comment: since you are using a:link you should use this instead:
'.post_more a:link {
color:#FFF;
}'